# Problems with physics-inspired solutions?

Tags: reference-request, contest-math, physics, big-list

I'm looking for cool, competition-style problems that borrow ideas from physics in their solution.  For example, one I found in the book [Putnam and Beyond](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387684451) goes like this:

> Orthogonal to each face of a polyhedron $S$ construct an outward vector with length numerically equal to the area of the face. Prove that the sum of all these vectors is equal to zero.

Solution:

> Assume that the interior $V$ of polyhedron $S$ is filled with gas at a (not necessarily constant) pressure $p$. The force that the gas exerts on S is $\int\int_S p \:\hat{n} \: dA$, where $\hat{n}$ is the outward normal vector to the surface of the polyhedron and $dA$ is the area element. The divergence theorem implies that $$\int \int_S p\:\hat{n}\: dA = \int\int\int_V \nabla p \:dV$$
>   Here $\nabla p$ denotes the gradient of $p$. If the pressure p is constant, then the right-hand side is equal to zero. This is the case with our polyhedron, where $p = 1$. The double integral is exactly the sum of the vectors under discussion, these vectors being the forces exerted by pressure on the faces.

I realize that, in retrospect, it is possible to purge any physics from this solution by just jumping straight to the divergence theorem, but regardless I like the fact that you can use a physical analogy (interpreting the vectors on the faces of the polyhedron as forces) to intuit a solution.  What are some other problems of this sort?

---

Comment 1: [I asked long ago whether a request for questions was on-topic](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23735/are-requests-for-problems-of-a-certain-type-on-topic), and got a tentative yes.

Comment 2: There are a few concepts from physics which I am confident can be used to good effect for pure math problems.  I'll mention a few in case it jogs someone's memory and helps them recall such a problem:

- The use of entropy/energy as a monotonic quantity in differential equations.
- Pauli matrices for rotations
- The concept of thermodynamic equilibrium (as used by Einstein to derive spontaneous emission coefficients).
- Fermat's principle for finding solutions to variational problems (as in the Brachistochrone problem).

Of course I also welcome problems that do not use these ideas!

Comment: Soap bubbles.  https://math.berkeley.edu/~sethian/2006/Applications/MinimalSurfaces/minimal.html

Comment: I just posted a problem on retrograde motion.  The problem contains a function $f(r)$.  According to physics $f(r)=f(1/r)r^{3/2}$, but I have only been able to verify this numerically.  Here is a link to the post  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286306/is-this-retrograde-motion-function-analytic-at-r-1

Comment: You can't do better than *The Mathematical Mechanic: Using Physical Reasoning to Solve Problems*, by Mark Levi. https://smile.amazon.com/Mathematical-Mechanic-Physical-Reasoning-Problems/dp/0691154562/ref=sr_1_2?crid=1B9LRZHXDZ51V&keywords=mathematical+mechanic&qid=1562551155&s=gateway&sprefix=mathematical+mech%2Caps%2C172&sr=8-2

Comment: Duplicate of a similar question : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46883/examples-of-using-physical-intuition-to-solve-math-problems

Comment: As well duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/457/305862 (in which one finds the pressure solution for the polyhedron)